# php mailer no pictures in gmail

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

in phpmailer I didn't see pictures in gmail, only if I press show images, same email sent from outlook (same text, same from, same smtp, same dkim, same x-mailer) it's OK.

Any ideas? I want phpmailer because i can rotate things in subject or from or bla bla.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook inlines image data to avoid client connections to outer sources. Instead of using external links with html bodies, use attached images or inlined HTML binary data with appropriate mimes during creation of e-mail body.

Here is an example code:

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64{binary_data_here}" />`